# f entire $f(n)=n^5$ and $ f (-\frac{n}{2} )=n^7$ . How many zeroes have $(f-\pi)(f-e)$ without using picard

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose f is an entire function satisfying $f(n)=n^5 $ and $ f (-\frac{n}{2} )=n^7 \forall n\in \Bbb Z_{>0}$. How many zeros does the function $g(z)= (f(z)-e)(g(z)-\pi)$ have?

Well... First note that $\infty$ is an essential singularity. So by Picard Theorem, every neighborhood of $\infty$  is surjective on $\Bbb C$ except at most for one point, and every other point have infinite preimages.

The problem is that I can't use Picard theorem, because we have not proved it. There is a way to do this only with elementary facts?

Comment: Is $g$ the same as $f$?